# c++ Templated Functor

Tags: c++, functor

Hi guys I'm new to c++ and I've a question regarding templated functor, I'm creating a simple templated functor on my own but just wondering why the value it returns is always "1" when i try to add two values together.

```
class AddValue{
private:
    int x;
public:
    template <class T, class U> 
    bool operator() (const T &v1, const U &v2)
    {   
        x = v1 + v2;
        return x;
    }
};

int main(){
    AddValue addvalue;
    int a = 3;
    int b = 6;
    cout<< addvalue(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  bool operator() (const T &v1, const U &v2) // You're returning bool
//^^ should be T
```

Also, you need

```
  T operator() (const T &v1, const U &v2)
    {   
        T x = v1 + v2; // Notice x type as T
        return x;
    }
```

See [Here](http://ideone.com/HpQdLw)

Comment: @POW thanks for the prompt reply and I appreciate it.. Am i right to say that if i'm comparing 2 different val than I would actually use `bool operator()` but if i want to return the value of any function than it would be `T operator()` and what does it mean by `T x`?

Comment: The return type and the addition is very tricky. T and V can be anything. But what is the result when you add them together? Did you mean to have `v1` and `v2` the same type?

Comment: @user2975932 yeah for comparison boolean outcome is desirable

Comment: @andre the value I get now is correct, why would u say that the return type and addition is very tricky?

Comment: @user2975932 `T x` simply means use the summed value as type `T`, it may be implicit type conversion, the final result is of type `T`. You can use `U` too

Comment: @user2975932 What should the return type of `addvalue((int)1, (float)0.1f)` be?